# Electromagnetic mass formulas when $\beta=\frac{v}{c}=0$

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, mass

I was reading Wikipedia article on *Electromagnetic mass*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_mass#Mass_and_speed.

I couldn't understand particular two formulas given under the section, *Mass and speed*. You can see the capture of section here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWkeK.jpg) .

First formula is by Searle $E_{e m}^{v}=E_{e m}\left[\frac{1}{\beta} \ln \frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}-1\right]$ where $\beta=\frac{v}{c}$.

The second formula is by Kaufmann $m_{L}=\frac{3}{4} \cdot m_{e m} \cdot \frac{1}{\beta^{2}}\left[-\frac{1}{\beta^{2}} \ln \left(\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}\right)+\frac{2}{1-\beta^{2}}\right]$

When $v=0$, one get $\beta=\frac{v}{c}=0$, and this produces infinity or undefined case for the both formulas above.

How did they handle such a case back then? I tried to go over the sources but couldn't really understand much. Would really it if you could help me!

Comment: The first limit is certainly not infinite, if you take it carefully, you should be able to show that $$\lim_{\beta\to 0}\frac{1}{\beta} \ln\left( \frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}\right) = 2,$$ and so $\lim_{\beta \to 0}E^v_{em} = E_{em}$, as you would probably expect...

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the second formula by Kaufmann does go to infinity/undefined case.

Comment: Kaufmann formula:

setting $m_{e m}=1$.

Series expansion at $\beta=0$.
$-\frac{3}{2 \beta^{3}}+\frac{3}{2 \beta^{2}}-\frac{1}{2 \beta}+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3 \beta}{10}+\frac{3 \beta^{2}}{2}-\frac{3 \beta^{3}}{14}+\frac{3 \beta^{4}}{2}-\frac{\beta^{5}}{6}+\frac{3 \beta^{6}}{2}-\frac{3 \beta^{7}}{22}+O\left(\beta^{8}\right)$
(Laurent series).

Notice the first three terms of the series; they are the problem. I still don't see how for $\beta=0$, you can get $m_{L}=m_{e m}$? Any help, please!

Comment: Aren't this formulas supposed to try to model high speeds? Why would they apply for $\beta\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: There is a typo in your formula for $m_L$, it should be $-1/\beta$ instead of $-1/\beta^2$ inside the square brackets.

Comment: @atarasenko Thank you very much! I was able to make $m_{L}=m_{em}$ for $\beta =0$. I wasn't able to do it earlier because of the typo. I don't know how to cancel the bounty now.